# background-image does not register with flask website

Tags: css, flask, jinja2, web-deployment

I have this file system:

```
app
    -templates
    -static
       -css 
          -category.css
       -images
          -image.jpg
```

My category.css

```
body
{
    background-image:url('static/images/image.jpg') <-- attempted with all levels of path
    background-image:url({{'/static/images/'image.jpg}}) ) <-- tried with it all in quotes as well
}
```

The thing is simple css such as styling p tags works but this doesn't. Any reason why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given that the image exists in the location, this should work,

```
body {
  background-image:url("{{ url_for('static', filename='images/image.jpg') }}");
}
```

Comment: did not work sadly. I have tried that already. Also if I do just background: red; it works so its not a css issue rather getting the image from the folder

Comment: Have you checked your browser to see if there is an error thrown in the console?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes something as simple as a hard reload --> ctrl+shift+r (on a Windows, or Apple + R or command + R on a Mac) can help because I know it's happened to me where the new css styling won't load until cache cleared or go for the hard reload.

Do you have a theme that may have css sheets overriding your own?